# How can I know return value count of a Lua function from C?

Tags: dynamic, count, lua, runtime, return-value

```
luaL_loadstring(L, "return 3, 4, 5");
int R       =   lua_pcall(L, 0, 3, 0);
```

Lua can return multiple values. But currently I have to hardcode the count of the return values. Can I know the count at runtime dynamically?

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

```
int top = lua_gettop(L);
luaL_loadstring(L, "return 3, 4, 5");
int R = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
int nresults = lua_gettop(L) - top;
```

You use `LUA_MULTRET`, and then use `lua_gettop` to figure out the top of the stack before and after the call.

Comment: Thanks! Just a remark for other people like me who did the mistake of missing the details: the (correct) sample above uses `luaL_loadstring` *to push a function on the stack*, if the function is already there (as it was in my case)  nresults will require a +1, or you'll end up with the wrong number of results (as in my case...).